# How do I know when to initiate multiple recursive calls within a single stack frame?

Tags: recursion

I solve a lot of recursive problems online in my spare time. Most the problems I solve are pretty straight forward and do not require you to combine returns statements. I recently was challenged to solve the fibonacci sequence and was unable to, the solution was:

```
public static int fib(int n) {
  if (n < 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("N must be more than zero");
  else if (n==0)
    return 0;
  else if(n==1)
    return 1;
  else
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

I traced through it and understand it, what I do not understand is how could I possibly come to a solution like this on my own? Specifically, how could I possibly know to initiate 2 recursive calls at the same time and then come them, like they do on line   `return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);`.

Is there some sort of key indicator that I am not seeing that should alarm me that I may need to activate multiple recursive calls and combine them?

I want to be able to solve recursive calls like this in the future but I can't see a pattern of behavior to identify. How do I know when to initiate multiple recursive calls within a single stack frame?

Comment: Simply because the *definition* of the Fibonacci series *is* `F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)`, with `F(n) = n if n < 2`. So the definition already involves two recursive calls. If you like to solve recursive problems, I suggest you try and learn the Scheme language and browse the [Scheme] tag here on SO. [Racket](http://racket-lang.org) is the easiest implementation to start with. This really opened my eyes on recursion.